# Visual Studio 2017 how to check for Xamarin updates

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2017

In Visual Studio 2017, how to check for Xamarin updates?

There's no Xamarin\Other tab anymore:

[image]

I found someone else complained and someone from Microsoft says it was fixed, but he doesn't say how it was fixed:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/22951/xamarin-doesnt-update-properly-vs-2017.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the Xamarin updates under Tools/Extensions and Updates, at this moment I have:

> Xamarin for Visual Studio 4.5.0.486
>
> Xamarin.Android SDK 7.3.1.2
>
> Xamarin.Apple SDK 10.10.0.37

I supose that Xamarin will update as equal to other Visual Studio extensions

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I guess I can file this one under `They moved my cheese™`

Comment: Also I think Xamarin updates as part of main VS2017 updates.